# How to get the time difference between two date stamps and arrange in DESCENDING ORDER

Tags: sql, redash

I need the time difference between two datestamps in hours and need to arrange them in descending order to get the median

```
SELECT "fulfillmentshistories"."fulfillmentid" as "Fulfillment ID" FROM FULFILLMENTHISTORIES
WHERE (Fulfillments."status" IN ('paid','delivered') AND (DATE("fulfillmenthistories"."createdAt") BETWEEN DATE('{{startDate}}') AND DATE('{{endDate}}')))
union
SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR,   'startDate'-'endDate') as DATEDIFF;
ORDER BY DATEDIFF, DESC
```

This is what I tried please help

```
SELECT "fulfillmentshistories"."fulfillmentid" as "Fulfillment ID" FROM    FULFILLMENTHISTORIES
WHERE (Fulfillments."status" IN ('paid','delivered') AND (DATE ("fulfillmenthistories"."createdAt") BETWEEN DATE('{{startDate}}') AND DATE('{{endDate}}')))
union
SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR,   'startDate'-'endDate') as DATEDIFF;
ORDER BY DATEDIFF, DESC
```

> Error running query: syntax error at or near "ORDER" LINE 5: ORDER BY DATEDIFF, DESC ^

Comment: `as DATEDIFF; ORDER BY DATEDIFF, DESC` should be `as DATEDIFF ORDER BY DATEDIFF DESC`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, 'startDate'-'endDate') as DATEDIFF; ORDER BY DATEDIFF, DESC
```

should be

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, 'startDate'-'endDate') as DATEDIFF ORDER BY DATEDIFF, DESC ;
```

and try avoiding alias names similar to the function name.

Comment: I dont see any change yet

Comment: Error running query: syntax error at or near "DESC" LINE 4: ...'startDate'-'endDate') as DATEDIFF ORDER BY DATEDIFF, DESC ; ^ 

This is the error im getting.

Comment: IS IT NECESSARY TO HAVE A FROM CLAUSE FOR THE SECOND SELECT STATEMENT TOO?

Answer (score 0):

```
UNION
SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR,   'startDate'-'endDate') as DATEDIFF;
ORDER BY DATEDIFF, DESC
```

should be

```
UNION
SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR,   'startDate'-'endDate') as DATEDIFF
ORDER BY DATEDIFF DESC;
```

Remove the semicolon after DATEDIFF and the comma after ORDER BY DATEDIFF. The semicolon should come at the end of the SQL statement since the whole of that is one sql statement.